# java.util.NoSuchElementException error, scan.next() problem

Tags: java

Creating a method that appends text to an existing file, but I keep getting an error

Notice that I only pasted the single method, not my entire code.

error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Unknown Source)
at Roster.Team.add(Team.java:47)
at Roster.Main.main(Main.java:22)
```

code:

```
    public void add(){
    System.out.println("Enter the name of the file that you wish to add information to: ");
    String name;
    name = scan.nextLine();
    try{
       BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(name, true));
        for(Player p : x)
            if(p != null){
                writer.write(p + "\n");
                writer.newLine();
            }
        writer.close();
    } catch (IOException e) { }
}
```

Comment: how did you instantiate scan? You should at least show all the relevant code. Also: never hide Exceptions. That' ll never do you any good

Comment: By which we mean - that `catch` block should contain at least an `e.printStackTrace()`. Anyway, do *not* post just your method without all the relevant information. Instead [edit] your question and post a [mcve]. I'm sure you're closing the scanner somewhere, and once you do that, you can't open a new one. Or something like that, but we can't tell that from the code you posted.

Comment: Check that you do not have more than one scanner object using `System.in` and also check that your scanner object hasn't been closed.

Comment: If you have resolved this issue itself as mentioned in a comment below then either post the solution you've found or remove the question if it is no longer relevant.

Answer (score -1):

You're getting this error because no line found in you scanner, add [check](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextLine()) to your code

```java
if (scan.hasNextLine()) {
    System.out.println("Enter the name of the file that you wish to add information to: ");
    String name;
    name = scan.nextLine();
    try{
       BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(name, true));
        for(Player p : x)
            if(p != null){
                writer.write(p + "\n");
                writer.newLine();
            }
        writer.close();
    } catch (IOException e) { 
        // it is better to log exception here
        e. printStackTrace();
    }
} else {
    System.out.println("Scanner has no lines to read.");
}
```

Check [tutorial](https://www.javatpoint.com/Scanner-class) how to use scanners in java.

Comment: Can you specify how to use it

Comment: Please check updated version. If hasNextLine returns false, it means that there is nothing to read from this scanner, and if you'll try it will cause java.util.NoSuchElementException.

Comment: What do you even mean by that? You have explained nothing on why there is nothing to read.

Comment: How could I know why there is nothing to read? I explained why you're getting this exception. If you want someone help you why there is nothing to read in your scanner, provide the code how did you initialised it. Possible reason is that you've reached end of the file.

Comment: I don't understand your code, how is the scanner supposed to have an answer (nextLine) before the question is asked?

Comment: Could you please try if it works, and if it is, I would suggest to read tutorial I've send.

Comment: If the answer help you, could you please mark it as the right answer?